# Visual Studio Code can't save ReadOnly file even as Administrator

Tags: save, visual-studio-code, readonly

I am running VSCode as administrator and while editing some read-only files I get the following message:
[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUDm9.png)

Then if I click: Retry as Admin... I get the following message: [click to see the next image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrRCG.png)

Afterwards I can click Retry as many times as I want but the second message will always appear.
To solve the issue I need to go to that file and remove the Read Only flag but it's so annoying to do that everytime. Ins't there a workaround for this? Thanks :).

Comment: The point of a read only file is that you're not suppose to be able to overwrite it. However, it could be read only for certain users or for users with specific privileges, such as admin. This is set at the operating system level so I assume that VSCode is making the suggestion that perhaps you can overwrite the file if you have admin privileges. In your case though, it seems as though you cannot. What file are you editing, is it one of your own files or is it a system file?

Comment: Hello @Bryan, it is my own file, part of a project that is checked in a CI/CD system. And when I pull the file it automatically gets set as a ReadOnly file. I know that's the purpose of the ReadOnly flag, but I would expect that a software developing tool such as VSCode to be able to overwrite it at need.